# Bash key value pair

Tags: bash, csv, hash

I am doing a bash scripts which reads in a csv file similar to:

```
Name, Surname, Course
X,    Y,       Maths,
A,    B,       Science,
C,    D,       Maths,
E,    F,       Science,
G,    H,       Science,
```

And I have tried to implement something like:

```
declare -a newmap
newmap[name]="${myarray[0]}"
newmap[course]="${myarray[3]}"

echo "Name ${newmap[name]}"
echo "Course ${newmap[course]}"
```

But I am not sure, how to use it while reading the file.

Thank you

Comment: See: [Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Comment: You need `declare -A`, not `declare -a` -- the latter only works with integers as indices. (As it is, it's evaluating `name` and `course` as numbers; both will evaluate to `0` unless you have a variable by that name with a numeric value in it).

Comment: ...that said, what's the actual question here? You don't provide any intended output or actual output to compare against, for example. There's some obviously-wrong code in this question, but one would need to know what your intended data structure is to know what would be *right*.

Comment: ...that said, for general guidance on reading files line-by-line (and distinguishing between fields) in bash, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: So, what I am trying to do is to loop through that csv file, and I am generating some unique ids for each course, then at the end of this process I wanted to replace each course under the "Course" column with its unique ID or at least creating an extra column with the ids, but the problem raises that I am not able to keep count which course has which id

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following if all you want is print to the console -

```
while read -r line;
do 
    IFS=',' read -ra myarray <<< $line

    [ "${myarray[0]}" == "Name" ] && continue

    echo "Name ${myarray[0]}"
    echo "Course ${myarray[2]}"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

This would read from your input file (change from console as used here). It then tokenizes each line by `,` to get the fields.

Comment: Any reason to `IFS=, read -ra`, as opposed to `IFS=, read -r name surname course`? I'd argue that names as opposed to numeric array positions is a bit more readable.

Comment: No @CharlesDuffy, nothing specific as such. Its just that I use it that ways. And yes I too agree it would be more legible the other way.